# Better way to plot a dataFrame on a plotly Table

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

Going over the documentation https://plotly.com/python/table/
I wanted to plot a data frame as a table

The documentation suggested the following

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2014_usa_states.csv')

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
    header=dict(values=list(df.columns),
                fill_color='paleturquoise',
                align='left'),
    cells=dict(values=[df.Rank, df.State, df.Postal, df.Population],
               fill_color='lavender',
               align='left'))
])

fig.show()
```

However, my dataframe is kind big and I wanted a better  way to input the values of the columns. Something that would be better than

```
....values=[df.Rank, df.State, df.Postal, df.Population]....
```

Answer (score 25):

After a bit of search I found an easy replacement. Pandas allows converting a whole dataframe into a list of lists.

Simply replace the line with

```
df.transpose().values.tolist()
```

So the final code looks like this

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2014_usa_states.csv')

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
    header=dict(values=list(df.columns),
                fill_color='paleturquoise',
                align='left'),
    cells=dict(values=df.transpose().values.tolist(),
               fill_color='lavender',
               align='left'))
])

fig.show()
```

## Reference

https://thispointer.com/pandas-convert-a-dataframe-into-a-list-of-rows-or-columns-in-python-list-of-lists/

Comment: I ran into the exact same problem. Greatly appreciate the answer. Works well.

Comment: Thanks man, this solved a lot of pain for me :-) `.transpose()` does only work Panda Dataframes. If someone (like me) got another format in spark, just add `.toPandas()` in front of transpose and it works like a charm!